# how to execute sql files through sql plus using command prompt via java but without using JDBC

Tags: sqlplus

This is a Swing UI which is shown in the figure, this figure is showing a box in which multiple sql files are present, I can choose multiple sql files and execute them by clicking execute selected Scripts.

**After clicking execute select Script button java should connect with command prompt, start sql plus in command prompt and execute all selected sql files one by one without using JDBC**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute SQL file from CMD prompt using Java ProcessBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020813/how-to-execute-sql-file-from-cmd-prompt-using-java-processbuilder)

Comment: No,It will execute through cmd but no need to give command manually.